# Flexible parameterized query

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a method that accepts an unknown amount of parameters using `*args`. I am trying to persist these parameters within a local Sqlite database.

```
def callingMethod(self):
    self.store("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4")


def store(self, *args):
    self.conn.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?,?,?,?)", args)
```

I cannot always assume that 4 arguments will be passed, but I have allowed for 4 in the parameterized query. Is there a way to accepting a flexible amount of values within my query?

Comment: If you have a *unknown* amount of parameters and you want to store them in table columns, then it means you want an *unknown* number of columns. Database tables do not work that way, they always have a fixed number of columns.

Comment: I have a set amount of columns, but not always will a value be provided for that column as its not applicable.

Comment: You'd need to pass an argument anyways

Comment: This is poor design, but if you can expect *at most* n arguments, then your table should have n+1 columns. Add logic to determine how many actual arguments the function receives, then insert blank values accordingly.